# Permission denied error in unix while trying to access folder of same server

Tags: unix, permission-denied

Permission denied error in unix while trying to access folder of same server. I have 2 servers on same host.

```
Server1@host1: cd server2/path2/path
Permission denied.
```

I have gone to server 2 and tried chmod ugo+rwx server/path2/path

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact commands and the corresponding output instead of describing what you did. Format this as code, e.g. by using the `{}` tool of the editor field. Please explain what exactly you mean with the term *server* in "I have 2 *servers* on same host"? Show the output of `ls -ld server2 server2/path2 server2/path2/path`.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this sounds like it belongs to https://SuperUser.com or maybe to https://ServerFault.com